# Join two SQL SELECT statements and have output in different columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a Database with salary values of specific job types and am trying to get an output that separates the job, the amount of jobs with salary info given, and then the amount of jobs above a certain salary limit.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT job_list_name, COUNT(job_list_name) FROM Jobs_Salaries 
WHERE salary_range_low = "100K+" OR salary_range_low = "125K+" 
OR salary_range_low = "150K" OR salary_range_low = "200K+") AS t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT job_list_name, COUNT(job_list_name) FROM Jobs_Salaries 
WHERE indeed_salary != "None") AS t2
ON t1.job_list_name = t2.job_list_name
GROUP BY t1.job_list_name
ORDER BY COUNT(t2.job_list_name) DESC;
```

This is what I currently have yet my output is this:

```
MACHINE LEARNING ENGINEER|178
DATA ENGINEER|148
DATA SCIENTIST|122
DATA ANALYST|15
MACHINE LEARNING ENGINEER|241
DATA ANALYST|224
DATA ENGINEER|219
DATA SCIENTIST|187
DATA ANALYST|463|DATA ANALYST|871
```

the values above the last data analyst value being the separate outputs of each statement but I'm not sure why that last value is there. I'm trying to achieve an output like this:

```
Job Type                  # of Jobs with Salary Values   # of Jobs above $100k
DATA ENGINEER                        400                          150
DATA ANALYST                         300                          100
DATA SCIENTIST                       200                          125
MACHINE LEARNING ENGINEER            100                          100
```

With the values separated by the counts of each SELECT statement and being grouped by the Job Title. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Consider conditional aggregation by moving `WHERE` conditions to aggregated `SELECT` columns:

```sql
SELECT job_list_name, 
       SUM(indeed_salary != 'None') AS [# of Jobs with Salary Values],
       SUM(salary_range_low IN ('100K+', '125K+', '150K', '200K+')) AS [# of Jobs above $100k]
FROM Jobs_Salaries
GROUP BY job_list_name
ORDER BY COUNT(t2.job_list_name) DESC;
```